# 'auto' difference between pointers and references

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, template-argument-deduction

Given this code:

```
int& some_class::ret_ref(){
    return this->some_integer;
}
int* some_class::ret_ptr(){
    return &(this->some_integer);
}

int main(){
    some_class c;
    auto p=c.ret_ptr();
    auto r=c.ret_ref();
}
```

At compile time:

- `p` is `int*`
- `r` is `int`

Why was `auto` deduced as `int*` in `p` and it was not deduced as `int&` in `r`?

What is the rule here?